# indesign script: remove/hide all empty graphic frames placed in a specific layer

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I have a multipage indesign document and in it several layers; one layer is called **obrazy** and in this layer on every page some frames are placed (the frames are also styled with an object style called **obraz**), then some of the frames are filled with images and some remain empty; what I need is **a script (in javascript) to go through the document end move the empty frames into a different layer** (can be new or already existing) which will later be hidden. The script must only manipulate frames in a specific layer or with a specific object style since there are other frames in the other layers.
I have written several versions (and spent hours of experimenting and going through various sources and similar scripts) but still do not have a fully working solution. I guess I am missing some details... Any pointers or suggestions would be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ok, here is what is now working for me:

```
var dok = app.activeDocument;
var pocetstran = dok.pages.length;
var vrstvaobrazu = dok.layers.item("obrazy");

for (var j = 0; j<pocetstran; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < dok.layers.item("obrazy").rectangles.length; i++) {
        if ((dok.layers.item("obrazy").rectangles.item(i).images.length == 0)){
        dok.layers.item("obrazy").rectangles.item(i).remove();
        }
    }
}
```